# not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning

While handling with missing data for below columns from csv file it throws  TypeError.How to resolve this ?

```
trainData.Gender.fillna(trainData.Gender.max(),inplace =True)
trainData.Married.fillna(trainData.Married.max(),inplace=True)

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

trainData.dtypes
    Loan_ID               object
    Gender                object
    Married               object
    Dependents            object
    Education             object
    Self_Employed         object
    ApplicantIncome        int64
    CoapplicantIncome    float64
    LoanAmount           float64
    Loan_Amount_Term     float64
    Credit_History       float64
    Property_Area         object
    Loan_Status           object
```

Answer (score 6):

Doing it that way you are actually considering missing data(NaN, which are treated as floats) to look for the maximum value. So:

```
trainData.Gender.fillna(trainData.Gender.max(),inplace =True)
```

will try to compare str vs. floats.

You need to do:

```
trainData.Gender.fillna(trainData.Gender.dropna().max(),inplace =True)
trainData.Gender.fillna(trainData.Married.dropna().max(),inplace =True)
```

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem while fitting my model.

I did:

```
trainData=trainData.fillna("")
```

And it solved my problem. Agree to @VictorGGI words above. Missing values is taken as `float`, whereas others are `str`.

Comment: you saved me thax

Answer (score 3):

I faced a very similar issue with the error message saying : ‘<’ not supported between instances of ‘float’ and ‘str’

I was trying to compute mode in a particular column named 'Outlet_Size' for specific values in another column named 'Outlet_Type' in a dataset I am working on.

As it turned out, the missing values in the column 'Outlet_Size' (which I was trying to impute and that was the motive behind computing the mean) was the obstacle itself as Panda would take those missing values (or NaN) as float type, while the rest of the values in that column were strings and obviously it was not able to find the mode.

The solution was to fill those missing values with blank strings.

```
data.Outlet_Size = data.Outlet_Size.fillna('')
```

As I did it for a particular column only, I used the above syntax. If I had to apply it to the entire dataset the it would have been,

```
data = data.fillna('')
```

For multiple columns the syntax would have been,

```
data[['column1','column2']] = data[['column1','column2']].fillna('')
```